# Can I use flip cards on click instead of hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, frontend, css-animations

I'm kinda new at CSS and I've been asked to modify some existing flip cards to flip on click instead of hover. Here's the code.

```
 .flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    /*increase the card width and height by 20px*/
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 600px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
    background-color: #ffca33;
    color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

I thought I could achieve this with changing `.flip-card:hover` to `.flip-card:active` but that only seems to work if I have the mouse button pressed down on it and flips back as soon as I let go. I tried `.flip-card:active.flip-card:hover` much to the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You cannot track click events with CSS. If you want click events, use JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card-front")[0]
    .onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active")
    }
```

Please note that this form will only take effect on the first flip card. If you want more, you need some kind of loop, or even setting an onclick event to the whole screen and checking if the target matches a flip card.